# Inequality Solution Set

Tags: inequality

Find the solution set for the inequality:

$|x-2| > |x+6|$

I'm just not sure how to work this out?

I've found the answer is $(-\infty,-2)$ using wolframAlpha, however there isn't a step by step.

If you could explain how I would go about trying to find the answer for myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since both sides of the inequality are nonnegative, it is safe to square both sides, yielding:
$$
x^2 - 4x + 4 > x^2 + 12x + 36
\iff -32 > 16x
\iff x < -2
$$

Answer (score 0):

Separate the cases:

1. $x \leq-6$ (so that $x-2$ is negative and $x+6$ is negative)
2. $-6\leq x\leq 2$ (so that $x-2$ is negative and $x+6$ is positive)
3. $x\geq 2$ (so that both expressions are positive)